# How to create CheckBox onClick Event in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm accessing the data for the CheckBoxes from the database, now I want to display the form for each and every checkbox if it's checked. How to achieve this?

My form design -

```
 <div class="col-sm-12" id="roomtypes">
     @foreach(var item in ViewBag.RoomTypes)
     {
         <input type="checkbox" id="chk_@item.id" name="RoomTypes" value="@item.id" /> @item.type<br />

         <div class="col-sm-12" style="display:none;" id="Price_@item.id">
             <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Price" id="PriceValue" />
         </div>
     }

</div>
```

I want to display the **price input** when checkbox is checked. 
My back-end code -

```
 ViewBag.RoomTypes = db.RoomTypes.ToList();
```

My code's generating this output - 
[My code's generating this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APaDf.png)

Comment: Bind a JavaScript event to the checkbox input. When the checkbox value changes, test the checkbox value, then make your price input visible or attach a new input (created in JavaScript) to your form.

Comment: Can u guide me how to do that for each check-boxes generated. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that with `css`. Add `chkshowhide` css class to your input and div and add `css` as per code. Your code will be as below.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="roomtypes">
     @foreach(var item in ViewBag.RoomTypes)
     {
         <input type="checkbox" id="chk_@item.id" name="RoomTypes" value="@item.id" class="chkshowhide"/> @item.type<br />

         <div class="col-sm-12 chkshowhide" id="Price_@item.id">
             <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Price" id="PriceValue" />
         </div>
     }
</div>
```

css.

```
div.chkshowhide {
    display: none;
}
input.chkshowhide:checked + br + div.chkshowhide {
    display: block;
}
```

You can test sample here.

```js
function saveData() {
  $('input.chkshowhide:checked').each(function() {
    var chkValue = $(this).val();
    var divId = this.id.replace("chk", "Price");
    var priceValue = $('#' + divId).find('input').val();
    console.log('chkValue=' + chkValue + ", priceValue=" + priceValue);
    // Write your save code here
  });
}
```

```css
div.chkshowhide {
    display: none;
}
input.chkshowhide:checked + br + div.chkshowhide {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_1" name="RoomTypes" value="1" class="chkshowhide"> 1<br />
<div class="col-sm-12 chkshowhide" id="Price_1">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Price" id="PriceValue" />
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="chk_2" name="RoomTypes" value="2" class="chkshowhide"> 2<br />
<div class="col-sm-12 chkshowhide" id="Price_2">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Price" id="PriceValue" />
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="chk_3" name="RoomTypes" value="3" class="chkshowhide"> 3<br />
<div class="col-sm-12 chkshowhide" id="Price_3">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Price" id="PriceValue" />
</div>
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="saveData();" />
```

Comment: Now suppose, I need to save these details individually (one by one - depends on the number of check-boxes checked) to database, how to do that in MVC?

Comment: @GautamSharma Updated code for Save one by one data for each checked input.